# How to predict values up to two weeks ahead?

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have a data frame that displays transaction numbers in 30-minute blocks since March 2016 to June 2018.

It consists of over 40,000 rows of data and looks like this:

```
    MeasurementTimeUtc Value
15 2016-03-01 07:00:00     0
16 2016-03-01 07:30:00     0
17 2016-03-01 08:00:00    19
18 2016-03-01 08:30:00    23
19 2016-03-01 09:00:00    23
20 2016-03-01 09:30:00    39
21 2016-03-01 10:00:00    35
22 2016-03-01 10:30:00    43
23 2016-03-01 11:00:00    27
24 2016-03-01 11:30:00    51
25 2016-03-01 12:00:00    41
26 2016-03-01 12:30:00    35
27 2016-03-01 13:00:00    41
28 2016-03-01 13:30:00    53
29 2016-03-01 14:00:00    33
30 2016-03-01 14:30:00    37
31 2016-03-01 15:00:00    31
32 2016-03-01 15:30:00    25
33 2016-03-01 16:00:00    23
34 2016-03-01 16:30:00     0
35 2016-03-01 17:00:00     0
```

The entire dataset follows a similar pattern (transactions typically occurring between 08:00 and 19:00).

The first time block in the data frame is `2016-03-01 00:00:00` and the final time block is `2018-06-30 23:30:00`.

**(Ideally using R) What is the best way to predict values up to two weeks ahead (up until 14th July 2018) given the 30-minute time block format?**

Is there a particular method that is better than others for data of this format?

Ideally, I would like the output to be a resulting data frame which effectively extends the original data frame and which mirrors the same format (two columns, with (up to) 14 rows).

Here are the first 100 rows from the data frame:

```
structure(list(MeasurementTimeUtc = structure(c(1456790400, 1456792200, 
1456794000, 1456795800, 1456797600, 1456799400, 1456801200, 1456803000, 
1456804800, 1456806600, 1456808400, 1456810200, 1456812000, 1456813800, 
1456815600, 1456817400, 1456819200, 1456821000, 1456822800, 1456824600, 
1456826400, 1456828200, 1456830000, 1456831800, 1456833600, 1456835400, 
1456837200, 1456839000, 1456840800, 1456842600, 1456844400, 1456846200, 
1456848000, 1456849800, 1456851600, 1456853400, 1456855200, 1456857000, 
1456858800, 1456860600, 1456862400, 1456864200, 1456866000, 1456867800, 
1456869600, 1456871400, 1456873200, 1456875000, 1456876800, 1456878600, 
1456880400, 1456882200, 1456884000, 1456885800, 1456887600, 1456889400, 
1456891200, 1456893000, 1456894800, 1456896600, 1456898400, 1456900200, 
1456902000, 1456903800, 1456905600, 1456907400, 1456909200, 1456911000, 
1456912800, 1456914600, 1456916400, 1456918200, 1456920000, 1456921800, 
1456923600, 1456925400, 1456927200, 1456929000, 1456930800, 1456932600, 
1456934400, 1456936200, 1456938000, 1456939800, 1456941600, 1456943400, 
1456945200, 1456947000, 1456948800, 1456950600, 1456952400, 1456954200, 
1456956000, 1456957800, 1456959600, 1456961400, 1456963200, 1456965000, 
1456966800, 1456968600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 23L, 23L, 39L, 35L, 43L, 27L, 51L, 41L, 
    35L, 41L, 53L, 33L, 37L, 31L, 25L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 
    21L, 19L, 41L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 57L, 31L, 29L, 29L, 33L, 35L, 
    21L, 19L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What kind of data are these? Do you expect some kind of seasonality, or even [tag:multiple-seasonalities], e.g., intra-daily, intra-weekly, and intra-yearly? Note that any answer here will focus more on the algorithms, less on how to munge the result in a specific R data structure.

Comment: The algorithm is what I am most interested in (the reason I requested an R-based solution is because I am an R user).  The data are recorded in 30-minute blocks, continuously from March 2016 up until the end of June 2018.

Comment: A good start would be to create a time series object from your data using the `ts()` function in R. From here you can plot the data using `plot.ts` to see what kind of patterns are in the data which would illuminate what kind of model you actually want. I am loathe to do this myself with the provided data as you have only provided four and a half days of data which would only show daily trends and ignore any weekly or seasonal effect.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we still don't know what kind of data these are, and whether you expect [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities). This is important.

If you expect multiple seasonalities, you may want to look into [its tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) and see whether [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) or [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats) models may be helpful. These take a long time to fit. Both are available in the `forecast` package for R.

If you do not expect multiple seasonalities, you could try standard forecasting algorithms, like exponential smoothing (`forecast::ets()`).

You might profit from reading an introductory forecasting testbook. I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/), which uses R throughout.